# Merge objectS of object

Tags: javascript, object, merge

I would like to merge 2 objects that contains objects themselves.
Like this :

```
let selections = {
    123: {
        abc: {name: 'abc'},
        def: {name: 'def'}
    },
    456: {
        ghi: {name: 'ghi'},
        jkl: {name: 'jkl'}
    }
};

let flatSelections = Object.keys(selections).reduce((r, k) => {
    return selections[k];
}, {});

console.log(flatSelections);

/* expected data
flatSelections = {
    abc: {name: 'abc'},
    def: {name: 'def'},
    ghi: {name: 'ghi'},
    jkl: {name: 'jkl'}
};
*/
```

But I only have the selection['456'] as output. 
https://jsfiddle.net/benlesc/uw65bjo1/13/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually return the modified accumulator from reduce. Use `Object.assign` or `Spread syntax` to merge `accumulator i.e r` with item i.e `k`

Also use `Object.values` since you are concerned about values only.

```js
let selections = {
    123: {
        abc: {name: 'abc'},
        def: {name: 'def'}
    },
    456: {
        ghi: {name: 'ghi'},
        jkl: {name: 'jkl'}
    }
};

let flatSelections = Object.values(selections).reduce((r, k) => {
    return Object.assign(r, k)
}, {});

console.log(flatSelections);
```

Comment: Hi Shubham ! Thank you very much. Clear, simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the `reduce` on `Object.values()`.

```js
let selections = {
    123: {
        abc: {name: 'abc'},
        def: {name: 'def'}
    },
    456: {
        ghi: {name: 'ghi'},
        jkl: {name: 'jkl'}
    }
};

const res = Object.values(selections).reduce((a, c) => {
    return {...a, ...c};
}, {});

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%!important; top: 0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Object.assign()`

```js
let selections = {
    123: {
        abc: {name: 'abc'},
        def: {name: 'def'}
    },
    456: {
        ghi: {name: 'ghi'},
        jkl: {name: 'jkl'}
    }
};

let output = Object.assign(selections["123"] , selections["456"])
console.log(output)
```

You will get an output of

```
{"abc": {"name": "abc"}, "def": {"name": "def"}, "ghi": {"name": "ghi"}, "jkl": {"name": "jkl"}}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I know this possibilitiy. But it was about to do it whithout knowing the object keys (123 or 456) it could be anything.